# How to Limit Results Per Match on a Left Join - SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, email

I have a table with student info [STU] and a table with parent info [PAR]. I want to return an email address for each student, **but just one.** So I run this query:

```
SELECT [STU].[ID], [PAR].[EM]
FROM (SELECT [STU].* FROM DB1.STU) 
STU LEFT JOIN (SELECT [PAR].* FROM DB1.PAR) PAR ON [STU].[ID] = [PAR].[ID]
```

This gives me the below table:

```
Student ID  ParentEmail
1         jim@email.com
1         sarah@email.com
2         paul@email.com
2         tim@email.com
3         bill@email.com
3         frank@email.com
3         joyce@email.com
4         greg@email.com
5         tony@email.com
5         sam@email.com
```

Each student has multiple parent emails, but I only want one. In other words, I want the output to look like this:

```
Student ID  ParentEmail
1         jim@email.com
2         paul@email.com
3         frank@email.com
4         greg@email.com
5         sam@email.com
```

I've tried so many things. I've tried using `GROUP BY` and `MIN/MAX` and I've tried complex `CASE` statements, and I've tried `COALESCE` but I just can't seem to figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

I think `OUTER APPLY` is the simplest method:

```
SELECT [STU].[ID], [PAR].[EM]
FROM DB1.STU OUTER APPLY
     (SELECT TOP (1) [PAR].*
      FROM DB1.PAR
      WHERE [STU].[ID] = [PAR].[ID]
     ) PAR;
```

Normally, there would be an `ORDER BY` in the subquery, to give you control over *which* email you want -- the longest, shortest, oldest, or whatever.  Without an `ORDER BY` it returns just one email, which is what you are asking for.

Comment: Thank you this seems to be what I need! Would you mind going more in-depth about how I might use `ORDER BY` to return the longest email in an `OUTER APPLY` situation?

Comment: You would put `order by len(par.em) desc` in the subquery.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want one column from the parent table, a simple approach is a correlated subquery:

```
select 
    s.id student_id,
    (select max(p.em) from db1.par p where p.id = s.id) parent_email
from db1.stu s
```

This gives you the greatest parent email per student.

Comment: Ah great thank you! I see, so min/max cannot be used on a JOIN?